# Canary - AccessDeniedException: Access to KMS is not allowed

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, aws-secrets-manager

I have setup a simple synthetic transaction monitoring (canary) in aws, that running a POST HTTP request, against specific endpoint, using a secret keys defined in AWS Secretes Manager (ASM).

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const secretsManager = new AWS.SecretsManager();
const getKeyCert = async () => {
    var params = {
        SecretId: "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-west-1:443682978425:secret:Canary_BO_TLS_CER-LalJXG"
    };
    const key = await secretsManager.getSecretValue(params).promise();
    var params = {
        SecretId: "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-west-1:443682978425:secret:Canary_BO_TLS_CER-LalJXG"
    };
    const cert = await secretsManager.getSecretValue(params).promise();
}

var synthetics = require('Synthetics');
const log = require('SyntheticsLogger');
const syntheticsConfiguration = synthetics.getConfiguration();

const apiCanaryBlueprint = async function () {
    const [ key, cert ] = await getKeyCert();
    syntheticsConfiguration.setConfig({
        restrictedHeaders: [], // Value of these headers will be redacted from logs and reports
        restrictedUrlParameters: [] // Values of these url parameters will be redacted from logs and reports
    });
```

I have also attached the `GetSecretValue` policy, in the IAM. to the role that running the Canary.

But from some reason, i'm getting an error message that related to Key Management Service (KMS):

```
AccessDeniedException: Access to KMS is not allowed Stack: AccessDeniedException: Access to KMS is not allowed
```

Which is very interesting,
Because i did not encrypt the my secret in the AWS Secrets Manager (ASM).

which led me think, that maybe that could it be that Key Management Service (KMS) is encrypting secrets by default, if i didn't encrypt them from the first place?

I'm not sure how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

verify if secrets manager key is defined with "Encryption key"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).